# How can I open two connections on one session?

Tags: java, android, session, httpsession

My (chat) program starts a session almost immediately, then in a separate thread it uses long polling to maintain a connection with it until it receives information.

```
while(Globals.clientIsLoggedIn) {
    ...
    response = client.execute(getRequest); // waits up to a minute for changes
    ...
}
```

<sup>(Globals is a set of "global" variables)

Client is my DefaultHTTPClient</sup>

I would like to have it concurrently be able to send messages to the server, using the same session!

```
response = client.execute(postMessageRequest);

...

client.execute(logoffRequest);
```

I know I must be missing something somewhere, but finding documentation for this (passing a session variable between two different HTTPConnections perhaps?) is a real bear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was while I was still searching for how to *explain* my problem, let alone answer it. The solution I found is detailed here:

[What is a good way to share a session between two HTTPClients in a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097216/what-is-a-good-way-to-share-a-session-between-two-httpclients-in-a-java-program)