# What is a good way to share a session between two HTTPClients in a Java program?

Tags: java, android, session, session-cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been developing an Android/Java application that opens up two simultaneous Apache HTTP connections. I have been developing a Chat application, and one connection is almost always running (the server was long polling; it would only respond once changes were made), and a second request to send data to the same site, using the same Session (due to being "logged in") was needed.

After plenty of searching on StackOverflow, I have not found a good way to do this. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example creates an HTTPClient from scratch. It then pulls the cookies out from another client, and adds it to its own. I've found this works without a hitch in Android.

```
        DefaultHttpClient sendClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        CookieStore originalCookies = Globals.getClient().getCookieStore();
        sendClient.setCookieStore(originalCookies);
```

Comment: Is this the ONLY way to share a session?